# Displaying List values in a Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary where the key is the athlete’s first and last name stored as a tuple, and the value is a list containing the athlete’s country and finishing time in hours, minutes
and seconds (in a tuple) as shown below:

```
dict={(Richard,Ringer):[Germany,(2,11,27)],
(Eliud,Kipchoge):[Kenya,(2,8,38)],
(Yavuz,Agrali):[Turkey,(2,15,5)],
...}
```

I managed to display the name and surname since it is in a tuple by creating a simple for loop, but I have no idea how can I display the list part.

```
for i in dict:
        name=i[0]
        surname=i[1]
        print(name+' '+surname)
```

Is there a similar way to print list of items in a dictionary?

Comment: `print(dict)` will display the dictionary automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data={('Richard','Ringer'):['Germany',(2,11,27)],('Eliud','Kipchoge'):['Kenya',(2,8,38)],('Yavuz','Agrali'):['Turkey',(2,15,5)]}

info = []
for item in dict(data):
    info.append({
        'name': item[0],
        'surname': item[1],
        'country': data[item][0],
        'finishing_time': {
            "hours": data[item][1][0],
            "minutes": data[item][1][1],
            "seconds": data[item][1][2],
        }
    })
print(info);
```

Output :-

```
[{'name': 'Richard',
  'surname': 'Ringer',
  'country': 'Germany',
  'finishing_time': {'hours': 2, 'minutes': 11, 'seconds': 27}},
 {'name': 'Eliud',
  'surname': 'Kipchoge',
  'country': 'Kenya',
  'finishing_time': {'hours': 2, 'minutes': 8, 'seconds': 38}},
 {'name': 'Yavuz',
  'surname': 'Agrali',
  'country': 'Turkey',
  'finishing_time': {'hours': 2, 'minutes': 15, 'seconds': 5}}]
```